# VueJS click doesn't work on mobile, click listener is not detected

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, mobile, onclicklistener

I'm trying to figure out where the problem is with VueJS on click listener.
So here i have a list of possible language that a user can choose from:

- EN
- FR
- IT

this list is wrapped into a `<div>` that shows or hide the list by using a click listener, the problem is that it only works on desktop and not on mobile

Here some video i captured to show you where is the problem

[Desktop (here is working as expected)](https://youtu.be/IeBk6FliT1Y)

[Mobile (here is not working anymore)](https://youtu.be/qKhZhjkibe0)

And here there is the code i'm now using for the component

```html
<template>
  <div @click="toggleList = !toggleList" class="lang-area" title="Change language">
    <ul class="lang-data">
      <li>{{ currentLanguage | uppercase }}</li>
      <li :key="index"
          @click="selectLang(lang)"
          class="lang-select"
          v-for="(lang, index) in listLanguages"
          v-if="toggleList">
        {{ lang | uppercase }}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <img alt="list languages" class="lang-list"
         src="../../static/icons/language-icon.svg">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    language: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currentLanguage: this.language,
      toggleList: false,
      languageList: ['en', 'fr', 'it'],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    listLanguages() {
      return this.languageList.filter(lang => lang !== this.currentLanguage);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    selectLang(lang) {
      this.currentLanguage = lang;
      this.$emit('languageChanged', this.currentLanguage);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="sass">
  @import "LanguageList"
</style>
```

As you can see i use the `toggleList` variable to toggle the language list
and by doing some tests if i click on the `<div>` it doesn't catch the event
I've even tried other libraries like [HammerJS](https://hammerjs.github.io/) but nothing is working

Comment: i tried with `@click.native` but the click is not triggered at all, i don't think is something related to css because i checked it in the inspector

Comment: Not sure in which environment/browser you run your code but it seems to work on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/791807/ even on my Moto X phone (using chrome on android). can you share your hammerjs solution?

Comment: how did you solved this issue? i have the same problem

Comment: @ReyYoung it was a css problem

Comment: @Andrea can you elaborate css problem. i think i'm facing the same problem

Comment: @ReyYoung it would be nice to share your experience, I have the same problem but don't see what the css problem could be.

Comment: @BrilBroeder i may not have solved this issue but the op did

Comment: I had the same issue. After seeing the comments here I went back to check my html/css. Turns out that some responsive styling was causing another element to overlay on the element I was trying to click. That overlay element had its own click handler and that was being triggered instead. I should have realized this as when I inspected the element via chrome it always took me to a different element on the page!

Comment: This is happening with me as well, seems like an issue with @dblclick event listner in vue.js

Comment: @click.native="" is deprecated and no longer supported.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue.

I placed @click events on anchor elements. They worked perfectly fine on the desktop, but they didn't work on the phone, or when changing the devtools to responsive mode.

```js
<a @click="console.log('clicked')"></a>
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63071591/vue-js-click-event-works-with-mouse-but-not-when-tapping-the-laptop-trackpad) then lead me to the discovery, that I need to add a @touchend event besides the click event for it to work.

```js
<a @click="console.log('clicked')" @touchend="console.log('clicked')"></a>
```