# Vue.js click event works with mouse, but not when tapping the laptop trackpad

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following elements in Vue:

```
<div class="search-result" v-for="result in search_results" v-on:click="submit(result)">
    {{ result.name }}
</div>
```

This displays a list of search results. On clicking a result, the `submit` method fires.

But, it doesn't always work.

- it works when I use my Macbook
- it works when I use a mouse on a Windows laptop
- it does NOT work when I use the trackpad on that same Windows laptop; more precisely, it doesn't work when I just tap the trackpad as I normally would. It works when I press it deeply.

Any explanation and/or solution?

What the `submit` method does is not really relevant, I've reduced it to `console.log('what is happening')` for testing and I am getting the same results above.

Comment: have you tried using another windows laptop? seems like this may be the trackpad issue? is the trackpad working otherwise?

Comment: It's working normally otherwise.

Comment: I suggest you try another windows laptop if possible. I also suggest you try another browser on your current laptop

Answer (score 1):

The trackpad is possibly sending a [`touch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) event instead of `click`.

To test this, use the DeviceToolbar in the Chrome inspector, and see if emulating mobile usage of the component also fails.

If so, try `v-touch`.